# syntax error at or near "auto_increment"

Tags: sql, postgresql

При попытке создать таблицу:

```
create table employee
(
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
fullname varchar(50) not null,
email varchar(50) not null,
gender varchar(50) not null,
hobbies varchar(50) not null,
country varchar(50) not null,
address varchar(50) not null
)
```

Возникает ошибка

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "auto_increment"
СТРОКА 5: id int not null primary key auto_increment,
```

Comment: В постгрессе нет такой буквы, как `auto_increment`. Используйте тип `serial`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-numeric.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

```
id int not null primary key auto_increment,
```

используйте

```
id serial primary key,
```

так как в PostrgreSQL `auto_increment` не существует - см. [PostgreSQL - AUTO INCREMENT](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_using_autoincrement.htm).